# Find a basis for the kernel and a basis for the image of the given linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis for the kernel and the basis for the image of the  linear transformation $T: P_2 (\mathbb{R})$ $\rightarrow$ $ P_2 (\mathbb{R})$ given by $T(p) = p' + p''$

I've found that $T(ax^2 + bx +c) = 2ax + 2a + b$.

So I think that the kernel of T is the set {$ax^2 + bx + c | 2ax + b + 2a$}.

I guess that's right, however, the question wants the basis for the kernel and not the kernel itself, so I'm confused.

I know that there is a dependence between $a$, $b$ and $x$. Should I write $x$ as function of a and $b$? It seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found correctly the action of $T$; now
$$
\ker T=\{ax^2+bx+c:2ax+b+2a=0\}
$$
that is $2a=0$ and $2a+b=0$. Now a basis for the kernel should be obvious, by just rewriting the conditions.

For the image you know that a set of generators is given by $T(1)=0$, $T(x)=1$, $T(x^2)=2x+2$. You can extract a basis of the image from them.